# How to properly escape whitespaces in filenames for ffprobe with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract parameters from video files with ffprobe and process depding on these results.
However i am not able to pass the files properly to ffprobe if they contain whitespaces.

```
echo $1

inputfile=$(printf '%q' "$1")
#inputfile=${1@Q}

echo $inputfile

ffprobeout= ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate -of csv=s=x:p=0 $inputfile
```

when i now call a smaple file  with
`files2reenc.sh "test file with spaces.mp4"`
it results

```
test file with spaces.mp4
test\ file\ with\ spaces.mp4

Argument 'file' provided as input filename, but 'test' was already specified.
```

So ffprobe sees every part of the name as seperate file and does not recognize it as one parameter. I'm not sure how to pass/escape my input so it would work as expected. I'm not sure if the problem is already when invoking my bash script or with the way i try to handle input paramter. I also tried using
`echo $inputfile | xargs -0 ffprobe ...` with no success.

Comment: Did you try putting $inputfile inside double quotes in the last line "$inputfile"

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I could have sworn i tried that already. Of course i needed to use $1 without further escaping then.

Comment: Related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rAlen for the quick hint - I needed to use the unchanged input and simply quote it.

```
inputfile=$1
ffprobeout= ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$inputfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

apropos of nothing, line continuations can aid readability for long lines:

```bsh
ffprobeout= ffprobe -v error \
                    -select_streams v:0 \
                    -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate \
                    -of csv=s=x:p=0 \
                    "$inputfile"
```